# Why doesn't filter: contrast doesn't work?

Tags: css, filter, css-selectors, styles, css-filters

So I'm trying to achieve so called gooey effect with css filter blur and contrast properties. However for some reason contrast doesn't work ? Any ideas why ?

I'm pasting my HTML and CSS below.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="liquid">
            <div class="left">
                
            </div>
            <div class="right">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

SCSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.liquid {
    display: flex;
    filter: contrast(20);

    .left,
    .right {
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        background-color: black;
        border-radius: 50%;
        filter: blur(10px);
    }

    .left {
        animation: anim-1 2s infinite linear;
    }

    .right {
        animation: anim-2 2s infinite linear;
    }
}

@keyframes anim-1 {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(50%);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(50%);
    }
}

@keyframes anim-2 {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
}
```

Comment: Filter's don't cascade - only the last applied is retained

Answer (score 1):

Try putting contrast on the same line that the blur filter is, separated by a space between properties:

```css
.left,
.right {
  ...
  filter: blur(10px) contrast(20);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With contrast filter you have to use % so just define filter:contrast(20%) and it should work fine

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work either. I have tried px, %, no unit, everything and it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've found why. I needed to add a background color to the div which also has  the contrast filter